# Why won't python plot this function correctly?

Tags: python

I'm plotting a function of the combined gravitational effects of the Earth and the moon at points between them. There should be a root where they cancel out but instead there's something that looks like a singularity. Excel manages to plot this graph properly. Maybe it's due to the very small and very large constants? If anyone could give me advice that would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from ridder import *

G=float(6.674*10**-11)
M=float(6.974*10**24)
m=float(7.348*10**22)
R=float(3.844*10**8)
w=float(2.662*10**-6)

x=np.arange(332000000,333000000,100)
y=((G*M)/(x**2))-((G*m)/((R-x)**2))-x*w**2
yroot=0*x

pl.plot(x,y,'-')
pl.plot(x,yroot)
pl.show()
```

the root is definitely between the start and end points of the array x.
changing the increment to higher numbers doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged [java]?

Comment: might be wrong here but maybe make x and y as `floats`?

Comment: why do you have `yroot = 0 * x`? Is it supposed to be zero, and if so why not just say `y = 0`?

Comment: @MattDMo: `x` isn't a scalar, it's an `ndarray`, so the OP is making sure that `yroot` is an array of the same shape as `x` but which is zero.

Comment: @DSM ah, you're right. Missed that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the image I get from your code:

[image: matplotlib graph]

I'm not sure exactly what is expected, but this seems reasonable.
If this isn't what you want, could you post your excel image?

Comment: That is what I am meant to get! Thank you, that tells me it's a problem with my particular system and not with the code.